# Access Object in Apex Class / Method after passing it from Controller

Tags: apex, class, method, helper

I (seemed to) have sucessfully passed an object from the client side helper controller into the apex method. However i am having trouble accessing using the dot notation i am used to in javascript and with queried objects in apex methods

Helper

```
fetchUpdaterHelper : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.updatePolicyValues");
    var why = component.get('v.initialRetrieve')[0];

    action.setParams({ 
        "rId": component.get("v.policyrecordID"),
        "sObj" : why});


    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Apex Method

```
@AuraEnabled
 public static void updatePolicyValues (String rId, Map<String, Object> 
 sObj) {
   Policies__c ValuestoUpdate = [SELECT Premium_Amount_RV__c, 
Cash_Surrender_Value_RV__c, Gross_Death_Benefit_RV__c, 
Values_as_of_RV__c FROM Policies__c WHERE Id = :rId]; 

   ValuestoUpdate.Gross_Death_Benefit_RV__c = 405000;
   System.debug(sObj);

   update ValuestoUpdate;
}
```

confirmation the object made it into the apex method
[image: picture of debug log]

what is the syntax to access the values within the passed in sObj parameter?
sObj.keyvalue does not seem to be working

Answer (score 3):

Because your `sObj` is of type `Map<String, Object>`, so to access the values within the map, you will need to fetch the values based on the key.

As an example (as in your screenshot), to fetch the value of `AV_Cash_Surrender_Value__c`, you will write:

```
Object val = sObj.get('AV_Cash_Surrender_Value__c');
```

The `Object` depends on the type of the value, so if the above value is say an Integer, you can write it as:

```
Integer val = (Integer) sObj.get('AV_Cash_Surrender_Value__c');
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you @Bobbygllh